# How do I prevent a single UIViewContoller from rotating in Monotouch? (All other views can rotate)

Tags: xamarin.ios, rotation, orientation

I have an iPhone app that supports all orientations but in one UIViewController I only want to support portrait (or upside down).

I have added the following code to my UIViewController but it still rotates.

```
public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation     toInterfaceOrientation)
    {
        // Return true for supported orientations
        return ((toInterfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft) && (toInterfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight));
    }
```

No matter where I add the ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation code it still rotates!

Is there a way to allow the app to support all orientations for all UIViewControllers except one?

Also i am using a NavigationController - does that affect things?

Answer (score 0):

if you use iOS 6 you must override GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations method instead ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

```
    public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
    { ... }
```

Comment: I've added: public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
  {
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
  }  But it still rotates!!

Answer (score 0):

Probably this happens because your root navigation controller brings it own rotation. Lets assume that your root navigation controller is a normal UINavigationViewController. Create a derived own version:

```
public class UINavigationControllerWithoutRotation : UINavigationController
{
    public UINavigationControllerWithoutRotation()
    {
    }

    public UINavigationControllerWithoutRotation(UIViewController viewController) : base(viewController)
    {
    }

    public override bool ShouldAutorotate()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now use this as the root controller. Find the code saying something like:

```
var myRootController = new UINavigationController();
```

and replace it with

```
var myRootController = new UINavigationControllerWithoutRotation();
```

That should do the job. Keep in mind, that you have to do it a little bit different if for instance your root view controller is a UITabBarController!